# Mouse and touchpad move at different speeds

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have a compaq 610 running windows 7, and I use a USB mouse on it.

The pointer speed is different for the mouse and the touchpad, so when I go to a meeting and take the notebook but not the mouse, the pointer moves too slow using the touchpad and I have to manually adjust it (of course when I return, I have to slow it down because the mouse would move the pointer too fast).

Is there any way to fix this, or to have this setting separate for both devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another choice is to use AutoHotKey which is completely free. See [this forum thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic14795.html) or [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/59707/autohotkey-modifying-the-mouse-touchpad-pointer-speed). I used it and it works well for me, I set F12 to switch between slow and fast speeds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Automatic Mouse Switcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automousesw/), wich is Free (GPL) and automatic.

Comment: It's bit of a pain to set up, but then it worked for me on Win7 64 bit. The main pain is that the installer needs administrative rights, but it doesn't pop up the UAC dialog, nor there's "Run as Administrator" for `.msi` files (unlike for `.exe`-s). So instead start `cmd` as administrator and there issue `msiexec /a automousesw.msi`. The GUI isn't self explanatory either, so you should read the Manual... The up to 1 minutes of delay of propagating the configuration changes can be confusing for example, when you try to experiment.

Comment: (Also, it doesn't add any Start menu or desktop shortcuts, so if you have to configure it ever again, it's here: `C:\Automatic Mouse Switcher\ams_config.exe`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think these might be exactly what you need: [Mouse Switcher](http://www.mouseswitcher.com) and [Mouse Speed Switcher](http://www.gphotoshow.com/mouse-speed-switcher.php).

Comment: They look good, I'd prefer something free though

Comment: Don't we all ? :) You can try Mouse Speed Switcher for free, without time limit (unlike Mouse Switcher), as long as you don't mind the nag screen telling you to buy the unlocked version. Other than that, I'm not really sure there is a 100% free solution for this tho.

Comment: Mouse Switcher no longer exists. Mouse Speed Switcher seems to be manual...I wonder if there is anything automatic?