# Setting mouse sensitivity per device in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, ergonomics

Is there any way (built-in or 3rd party application) to set per-device mouse sensitivity settings in Windows 7? Two mice behave differently and constantly need to switch sensitivities when switching between which mouse is in use.

Comment: I am a little shocked this question has only 3 votes right now... millions of people I assume have laptops with docking stations and mice with different sensitivity.

Comment: Maybe the problem for me is that my mouse is a super-sensitive gaming mouse... so the touchpad/mouse behave radically different?

Answer (score 15):

For me Eithermouse works the best in windows 8.

It automatically switches settings when using touchpad or mouse. This way the speed settings get automatically adjusted.

http://www.eithermouse.com/

From their website:

> Multiple mice, individual settings!
>
> Instantly changes settings when any mouse is used:
>
> - swap buttons
> - mirror cursor
> - adjust speeds
> - and more...
>
> Leave multiple mice on a pc and automatically swap buttons on each mouse
> Have a left-handed and a right-handed mouse always connected and ready to use
> Great for multi-user/public workstations to accomodate both left and right handed users.
>
> Possibly helps with RSI/injury issues by allowing switching between left and right hand.
>
> Easily swap mouse buttons from system tray if only one mouse is used
>
> Tray icon points to active mouse
>
> Freeware! no ads, no nags, free software, suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Milan, please add some clarification 'why'. Do not just post links. Your answer looks spammy that way.

Comment: Milan, as per the other comments, I've added additional detail about what the software is/does

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks, next time I will add some more information :)

Comment: I chose this solution over AutoSensitivity, since AutoSensitivity claims to be "based on mouse connect / disconnect", whereas EitherMouse switches between configurations whenever you move the mouse in question. (So even if you have your regular mouse connected, you can still use the trackpad and it will use your trackpad settings.)

Comment: I have a normal mouse and a trackball. For the latter I wanted higher speed. Eithermouse allows you to do that, without having to disconnect either one. Does the job perfectly, and can be downloaded as a stand-alone executable.

Comment: VirusTotal (a few of the sources) and Windows say there is malware in this...

Comment: Download blocked by Chrome, Firefox (with option to download anyway). Avast qurantines it reporting FileRepMalware

Answer (score 5):

If Moab's solution is not suitable, I suggest trying these two software solutions:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/automousesw/
- http://autosensitivity.codeplex.com/

I am personally not inclined towards using Moab's because it has the "auto-nag until you buy it" (reminds me too much of spyware... and I know it will interrupt my workflow constantly).

I looked at screenshots for both and saw that "automousesw" has 4 super complex GUI screenshots and "AutoSensitivity" has ONE simple GUI screenshot:

[image: Yea! something simple and elegant]

"AutoSensitivity" is a no-brainer choice for me... (keep it simple stupid). I am downloading it now. If there is no update to this post... then I have either been killed by it... or it works as advertised.

Comment: Did you die????

Comment: AutoSensitivity only supports one mouse and a touchpad. It does not work for two mice.

Answer (score 4):

See this app

http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/03/mouse-speed-switcher-configure-speed-settings-per-mouse/

> The mouse speed settings configured in Windows apply to every mouse connected to the computer system. A laptop’s touchpad for instance has the same speed settings as a mouse that gets connected to the laptop occasionally. While many computer users do not mind, some may prefer to configure the speed per mouse to improve their workflow.
>
> The free software program Mouse Speed Switcher is able to do that. The application can configure up to three different computer mice individually.
>
> Mouse Speed Switcher has been tested on a Windows 7 Professional 64-bit system.

Comment: The thing with this app is it's not actually free. Perhaps it was at one point but I've been using this and now it demands payment (or oddly, that I upgrade): http://www.gphotoshow.com/mss_purchase.php

Comment: You don't have to pay, only if you want to get rid of the nag reminder.

Answer (score 0):

That would be dependent on the drivers. I don't believe Windows has a way built in to do it at a per-device level, but many mice manufacturers provide that functionality when their drivers are installed. I would first make sure you have the manufacturer's drivers installed and not using the generic ones, and see then if there are additional configuration options available in mouse settings under Control Panel.

Comment: Yeah, but a quick way to switch or an app that looks at the hardware currently in use should be possible.