# Is there a way to adjust mouse pointer speed for individual monitors?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, mouse, logitech-mouse, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to adjust the mouse pointer speed for each individual monitor? I'm running two equally sized monitors, one is 4K, the other is 1080p, which means everything on the 1080p monitor is twice as large and moves twice as fast relative to the display area. What I'd like to do is have the mouse pointer switch to a lower speed when on the 1080p monitor. This should be doable with drivers or some scripting. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I can figure things out from there myself.

My current mouse is the Logitech M500 with the SetPoint driver software running under Windows 8.

Comment: [Setting mouse sensitivity per device in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/225686/241386)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution that worked for me - go into Mouse Properties -> Pointer Options and tick 'Enhance pointer precision'. This causes pointer velocity to be consistent across screens with different resolutions.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. Worked perfect for me on my new 4k 27" monitor and my two 1050p montors

Comment: Why is this not the default in windows?  It works wonderfully!

Comment: It was the default on Windows 10, and disabling it made things WAY worse, though I will say with it on it still feels slow on the 4K monitor to me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, so I wrote an application to set mouse speed per monitor.  Source code (C#) is available; it's in the same ZIP as the executable. The program works by changing mouse sensitivity when the mouse pointer crosses a border.

Download: [Custom Screen Speed](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419035942/http://shanedidona.com/programspage)

Comment: Note to mods:  We're allows to self-link, right?  I couldn't find a solution other than the program I ended up writing.

Comment: not a mod, but I believe you are allow to self-link as long as you disclose the fact that you are doing so (it also helps that it's free/open source)

Comment: The link has expired.

Comment: @pepkin88 I fixed it; the Internet Archive had the page and the ZIP.

Comment: The original link to the programs page has been recreated from the Wayback Machine. I was doing some Drupal stuff and I suppose the page got deleted.  I'm glad to see people are using my program :)